# Springboot : Create EAR from springboot multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, multi-module

As per my project structure in springboot multimodule project

parent `<packaging>` pom`</packaging>`

serverchild `<packaging>` jar`</packaging>`

angularchild `<packaging>` jar`</packaging>`

I want to create a EAR file from this project structure to deploy it on websphere.
In some of the tutorial it is mentioned to add another child say

parent_ear `<packaging>` ear `</packaging>`

and add the dependency of serverchild and angularchild. But then I am not able to execute the maven update.

Is there any other way doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to create a parent level project `POM` file which includes both of your modules together. A typical example of the structure will look as follows:

**Parent POM**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>Parent</name>
<description>Application</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>server</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

*** Module POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>example-module</artifactId>
<packaging>jar<packaging>

<name>modules</name>
<description>Application</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
</project>
```

***EAR POM which has modules as dependecy***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>example-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear<packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-module</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I want to create a ear file of this project

Comment: Updated my answer @sparsh610

Comment: here one of the packaging is war, i dont know if it will work

Comment: I just included war as an example. You can simply use jar packaging. I just updated it to be jar @sparsh610

Comment: An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Can you post your code here and also the file structure?

Comment: I will add after this comment if required,it is showing for the ear module

"Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Select: Maven->Update Project... from the project context menu or use Quick Fix."

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: I m using myeclipse

Comment: Usually they are present under project structure settings

Comment: also facing this exception while running maven install, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException